# Convert Uint32 into an array of 4 bytes

Tags: types, dart, type-conversion

How can I convert a `Uint32` number into its 4 bytes (as a `Uint8List` or similar).

**Context**: I am using the `image` package, and calling `getPixel(x,y)` function, which returns a `Uint32`. I want to separate it out into the rgba color channels.

Comment: There are helper functions in `package:image` to get rgba components of a pixel. `getAlpha()`, `getRed()` etc. Using those seems simpler than converting.

Answer (score 5):

Turns out the way to do so is to convert it into a `Uint32List`, then retrieve the byte buffer and convert it to the type you want.

```
int pixel = image.getPixel(x, y);
Uint32List list = new Uint32List.fromList([pixel]);
Uint8List byte_data = list.buffer.asUint8List();
```

Comment: Another option is: `var bytes = ByteData(4); bytes.setUint32(0, pixel, Endian.little); var byte0 = bytes.getUint8(0);`. Or you can just do bit-operations: `var byte0 = pixel & 0xff; var byte1 = (pixel >> 8) & 0xff; var byte2 = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff; var byte4 = pixel >> 24;`.